# Select Query in ibatis with hashMap as parameterClass

Tags: java, sql, hashmap, ibatis

I have the following java Code

```
Map temp=new HashMap();
temp.put("RL_ID",rl_Id);
temp.put("User_Id",user_Id);
temp.put("URI",uri);
getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForMap("AuditReport",------remaining parameters------);
```

I want to access this map in ibatis and retrive the values of the map in a select query.

```
<select id="AuditReport" resultClass="java.util.HashMap" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap">
Select BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER.id from BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER WHERE -----remaining query---------
```

What will be an appropriate way to complete the remaining query and the java function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns names in `BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER` are the same as the params you're putting in the Map, you'll need to do something like this:

```
<select id="AuditReport" resultClass="java.util.HashMap" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap">
    Select BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER.id 
    from BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER
    WHERE BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER.RL_ID = #RL_ID#
    AND BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER.User_ID = #User_ID#
    AND BIO_RESEARCH_LOCATION_USER.URI = #URI#
</select>
```

If you don't want quotes around a param, you should use `$` instead of `#`. For e.g., if you don't want quotes around RL_ID, you'll need to use `$RL_ID$` instead of `#RL_ID#` above.